# Virtual hosts not working Ubuntu both sites direct to the same root 14 LTS and apache 2.4.7

Tags: 14.04, lamp, virtualhost

I have two sites and they are both located in the /var/www/ directory.

one is at...

```
/var/www/doamin1.com/public_html
```

the other is at...

```
/var/www/doamin2.com/public_html
```

directories are chown to the www-data:www-data user and group.

I have set up the conf files and they are

```
doamin1.com.conf
```

and

```
doamin2.com.conf
```

and they look like this...

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

        <Directory /var/www/domain1.com/public_html>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ServerName wildcard.domain1.com
        ServerAlias *.domain1.com
        ServerAdmin admin@domain1.com

        DocumentRoot /var/www/domain1.com/public_html

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>

#vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet

<VirtualHost *:80>

        <Directory /var/www/domain2.com/public_html>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ServerName wildcard.domain2.com
        ServerAlias *.domain2.com
        ServerAdmin admin@domain2.com

        DocumentRoot /var/www/domain2.com/public_html

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>

#vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

added the domains to the host file `/etc/hosts`

```
a2dissite 000-default.conf

a2ensite domain1.com.conf
a2ensite domain2.com.conf

service apache2 reload

service apache2 restart
```

and both domains still direct to the same domain, I even reboot the server and removed the wildcard setup...

```
ServerName domain1.com
ServerAlias domain1.com

ServerName domain2.com
ServerAlias domain2.com
```

and they don't direct correctly. Both domains are owned and DNS is pointing to the correct location. Everything I do still results in them both redirecting to the same directory.

I have links to my config files in the sites-enabled and conf files for each of my sites, still doesn't work. I am lost.

What am I missing here?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem!

Comment: Did you try the answer bellow? if not let me know what your setup is exactly.

Comment: yes and it worked. I first tought it isn't working becouse i had mispelled few letters! I spent atleast one working day handling this before i found this post. Thanks!

Comment: No problem glad I could help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I found was that for each virtual host configuration...

/etc/apache2/sites-availiable/doamin1.com.conf

and

/etc/apache2/sites-availiable/doamin2.com.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

*//configriation*

</VirtualHost>
```

I changed /etc/apache2/sites-availiable/doamin1.com.conf to look like this

```
<VirtualHost domain1.com:80>

*//configriation*

</VirtualHost>
```

and /etc/apache2/sites-availiable/doamin2.com.conf to look like this...

```
<VirtualHost domain2.com:80>

*//configriation*

</VirtualHost>
```

I think that this is because both files were looking for the *:80 directive in the opening line of the block. This then caused the server to revert to the first conf file and used the "DocumentRoot" in that virtual host block.